# ImageIO write load issue

Tags: java

```
    BufferedImage image = generateCaptchaImage(engine, cycle, output, height, width, fontSize, noOfBoxesToBeDrawn,
            noOfLinesToBeDrawn, alphabetCount, letterWidth, background, text);
    HttpServletResponse response = cycle.getRequestContext().getResponse();
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(response.getOutputStream());
    encoder.encode(image);
```

replaced above code with below, but my image is not getring rendered on htmp page

```
    BufferedImage image = generateCaptchaImage(engine, cycle, output, height, width, fontSize, noOfBoxesToBeDrawn,
            noOfLinesToBeDrawn, alphabetCount, letterWidth, background, text);
    HttpServletResponse response = cycle.getRequestContext().getResponse();
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",response.getOutputStream());
```

upgraded jdk from 1.6 to 1.8 and and changed some existing java code with ImageIO code
after that captcha image is not getting shown.

Comment: Did `ImageIO.write` return `true`?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, does ImageIO.write return true? I suspect not. There are two reasons I can think of that your image would not be properly written.

- Your JDK doesn't have a JPG codec. There was a licensing issue for .jpg.
- Your BufferedImage has an Alpha channel which jpg doesn't support.

The first issue you would need to download a new JDK, but I don't think this is relevant anymore.

The second issue can be resolved by creating an appropriate image and drawing the first image to it. Or use PNG. Which supports transparency.

Here is a compilable example.

```
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;

public class ImgIO{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.drawString("Hello Image", 50, 120);
        Graphics g2 = img2.getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ImageIO.write(img2, "jpg", new File("junk.jpg"));

    }

}
```

Note that it fails **silently** if you try to write `img` directly because it has an alpha channel.